# ansible "with_lines: cat somefile" fails in a skipped block

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with a block that has a when condition. Inside is a task with a loop. How can I change this loop so that when the condition is false the skipped task doesn't fail?

```
block:
  - name: create a file
    lineinfile:
      line: "Hello World"
      path: "{{my_testfile}}"
      create: yes

  - name: use the file
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ item}}"
    with_lines: cat "{{my_testfile}}"

when: false
```

```
TASK [create a file] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [use the file] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
cat: files/my/testfile: No such file or directory
fatal: [ipad-icpi01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "lookup_plugin.lines(cat \"files/mytestfile\") returned 1"}
```

Comment: `my_testfile` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, actually `my-testfile` is not valid but `my_testfile` is. I think you corrected on spot by habit in your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your failing task to the following which will always be able to run, even if the file does not exists, and will not use the shell or command where there is no need to:

```yaml
  - name: use the file
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ (lookup('file', my_testfile, errors='ignore') | default('', true)).split('\n') }}"
```

The key points:

- use the `file` lookup plugin with `errors='ignore'` so that it returns the file content or `None` rather than an error when file does not exists.
- use the `default` filter with second option to `true` so that it return default value if var exists but is null or empty.
- split the result on new lines to get a list of lines (empty list if file does not exist).

Note: as reported by @Vladimir, I corrected your var name which is not valid in ansible.

Comment: I'm not really happy with this, because it doesn't fail, but still produces a WARNING "Unable to find 'testfile' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)"

Answer (score 1):

Test the existence of the file. For example

```yaml
    - block:
        - name: create a file
          lineinfile:
            line: "Hello World"
            path: "{{ my_testfile }}"
            create: yes
        - name: use the file
          shell: '[ -f "{{ my_testfile }}" ] && cat {{ my_testfile }}'
          register: result
        - name: use the file
          debug: 
            msg: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
      when: false
```

The `lookup` plugin `file` should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a mix of the provided answers. These tasks will be skipped without failing or creating a warning.

```yaml
    - block:
        - name: create a file
          lineinfile:
            line: "Hello World"
            path: "{{ my_testfile }}"
            create: yes

        - name: get the file
          slurp:
            src: "{{ my_testfile }}"
          register: result

        - name: use the file
          debug: 
            msg: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ (result['content'] | b64decode).split('\n') }}"

      when: false
```

Comment: This *almost* works. Since it splits by newline, the very last line will usually also contain a `\n` and hence there will be an empty loop iteration at the very end, making your script crash.
A hacky fix is to use `"{{ (result['content'] | b64decode).split('\n')[:-1] }}"` to exclude the last `\n`. I tested this and it worked.